# Is there a reason why M can't be all summable sequence?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let M be the set of all summable non-negative sequences $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of real numbers, that is, $x_k \geq 0$ for all k and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ converges to a real number. Let $d:M \to \textbf{R}$ be defined by $d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k|$. Show that M, d is a metric space. Is there a reason why M can't be all summable sequences - why do we need non-negative?

$\textbf{Show that M,d is a metric space.}$

$\textbf{Proof:}$ For M to be a metric space, it must satisfy the following properties:

- If $\{x_k\},\{y_k\} \in M$ with $d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=0$, then $x_k=y_k$ (vice versa).

Let $\{x_k\},\{y_k\} \in M$. Assume $d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k|=0$.
$$ d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k|=0 \iff |x_k-y_k|=0 \iff $$  \begin{cases} 
      x_k-y_k=0 \iff x_k=y_k\\
      -(x_k-y_k)=0 \iff x_k=y_k\\
   \end{cases}
Hence $x_k=y_k$.

- If $\{x_k\},\{y_k\} \in M$, then $d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=d(\{y_k\},\{x_k\})$.

Let $\{x_k\},\{y_k\} \in M$. Assume $d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k|$.
$$d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |-(y_k-x_k)|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |y_k-x_k|=d(\{y_k\},\{x_k\})$$
Hence $d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})=d(\{y_k\},\{x_k\})$.

- Triangle Inequality
  Let $\{x_k\},\{y_k\},\{z_k\} \in M$. Assume $d(\{x_k\},\{z_k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-z_k|$.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(\{x_k\},\{z_k\}) & =\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-z_k| \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k+y_k-z_k|\\
& \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k| +|y_k-z_k|\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k-y_k| +\sum_{k=1}^\infty |y_k-z_k|\\
& =d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})+d(\{y_k\},\{z_k\}) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Hence $d(\{x_k\},\{z_k\}) \leq d(\{x_k\},\{y_k\})+d(\{y_k\},\{z_k\})$.

Hence M,d is a metric space.

$\textbf{Is there a reason why M can't be all summable sequence?}$

The reason why M can't be all summable sequence is because then the sequence might not converge, particularly when the sequence is negative, and we will get an infinite number when summming it.

Is this explanation correct?

Comment: The explanation for the last part is certainly not correct, since the hypotheses are that the sequence is summable. So you're not going to get an "infinite number" when summing it.

Comment: Hint: Can you think of two summable sequences for which the series that defines the "distance" does not converge? Hint: Pick one of the sequences to be all 0s, and the other to be *not* strictly positive or strictly negative (e.g., alternating might work...)

Comment: As John said, the distance function need not even be defined if the sequence is not *absolutely* summable (!). So this is in fact axiom 0: the metric has finite values. You haven't checked that.